# Javascript regex to match correct price value

Tags: javascript

Following is my javascript code which only accept number and dot (.). But If I write 123.....122 It's still accept. Basically I'm doing this for price field validation where user can only write this format.

**Desire Format:**

```
$(currency)12345(amount).(dot only once)123(decimal)
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
</script>
```

**Html Input field:**

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)' />
```

How can I fix this javascript code ?
Thanks.

Comment: so you want it to match, for example, `$845.47`?

Comment: @Markasoftware Yes, this is my currency format.

Comment: you're just testing the key they press. You need to test the entire input

Comment: @Markasoftware, So if i use this then will it work ? var regex = /^(\d*([.,](?=\d{3}))?\d+)+((?!\2)[.,]\d\d)?$/;

Comment: @Babu just tested that, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Note that validating on keyboard events isn't enough, because the user may change the value without using the keyboard...

Comment: @nnnnnn can you give real solution for that ?

Comment: Well you can run the same validation on `change` so that at least the value will be checked when the user clicks or tabs out of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with your code: you're only testing keypress, not the value of the input, and the regex is a bit messed up. Here's how to fix it:

JavaScript:

```
function validate(toValidate){
    if(!/^\$\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(toValidate))
        alert('NOOOOO');//or do something else here
}
```

HTML input:

```
<input type='text' oninput='validate(this.value)' />
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3KFDJ/2/)

Comment: It's not accepting $(Dollar) and It's showing "Nooo" when type a number.

Comment: @Babu whenever you type a key, it tests it against the regex. If it doesn't match, it shows the alert. Type $, click ok, then type 5 (it should say $5 now), and there's no alert, which means it passed. I'll edit the fiddle to make it more usable

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Did you test my uploaded script ? You can only type "Number" value. You can't type any alphabetic character. So this javascript validation should be valid while user typing which match my Format string...